# Is there Unit Test Framework in Orbeon?

Tags: unit-testing, xforms, orbeon

I am wondering if there is any **Unit testing framework** for testing the Orbeon Forms.
The unit testing that we are trying to attain are event check, enable-disable check, navigation checking, elements style checking etc...
I tried selenium IDE(using it as a Firefox plugin) as a POC. It had a ease in creating the test case.
But when I encountered repeated sections in my form, the id generated for each field was differing at times whenever we refresh the form. So had to drop the idea using selenium IDE.

I happen to see this [YDT-cleint side unit test](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/xforms-unit-tests<) link in orbeon wiki. But was not able to get much of idea about the usage of this YDT, or how to integrate with orbeon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit tests for Orbeon Forms itself fall into 3 categories:

1. JUnit-type tests, running on the server (e.g. [a test for Liferay](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/test/src/org/orbeon/oxf/portlet/LiferayContextTest.scala))
2. XPL-based tests, running on the server (e.g. [for XBL componnents](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/ops/unit-tests/xforms-server/tests-xforms-components.xml))
3. YUI Test-based tests, running on the browser (e.g. [a test for the autocomplete](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/autocomplete/autocomplete-unittest.js))

For applications/forms you write on Orbeon Forms, I would recommend you use Selenium. Since you need stable ids for Selenium, make sure to explicitly put an id attribute in your XForms on everything you'll want to test on in Selenium. (If you don't, as you've noticed, Orbeon Forms generates ids, which can easily change when you update your form.)

Comment: Avernet. Thanks for the links. Just one thing, I noticed in the documentation you had written that, you could infact have some sample application that will have the unit tests integrated to it. I found it really difficult to figure out where the code mentioned in the documentation should integrate with the orbeon forms.

Comment: @Babu, I am lost: what is the particular documentation you are referring to?

Comment: I am referring to the 3 categories of unit tests you had mentioned above - JUnit-type tests, XPL-based tests and YUI Test-based tests. All the 3 links that you had mentioned has a sample code for each kind of testing, But I am not able to figure out how those test cases are supposed to interact with Orbeon Forms. For example, if I have a input field in my orbeon form, how is the input field instance accessed in the Junit for testing the values.

Comment: @Babu, OK, got it. So, let's consider the YUI case. You would use `Document.getValue()` as done here: http://goo.gl/Fs9ga. The downside of using YUI Test for this is that you have to write JavaScript (or CoffeeScript) to create your unit test, and can't use a tool, like Selenium IDE. Also, you can only do what can done in JavaScript, e.g. you can't select a file to upload.